# Erro: RuntimeException ao tentar montar caso de teste

Tags: java, android, testes, junit

Estou tentando montar um teste simples, utilizando o espresso e aparecem os seguintes erros:

[image: Erro]

Código:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.annotations.VisibleForTesting;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.MediumTest;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.holandago.urbbox.b.LoginActivity;
import com.holandago.urbbox.b.MainActivity;
import com.holandago.urbbox.b.R;
import com.holandago.urbbox.b.model.user.User;
import com.holandago.urbbox.b.ride_details.RideDetailsFragment;
import com.holandago.urbbox.b.utils.JsonUtils;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MapsActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void TestEmail(){
        onView(withId(R.id.contact)).perform(click()).check(matches(withId(R.id.contact_us_container)));
    }

}
```

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'bAndroid'
            keyPassword 'abraao123'
            storePassword 'abraao123'
            storeFile file('../cer/android.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    lintOptions {
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.holandago.urbbox.b"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 66
        versionName "2.9.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            ext.betaDistributionEmails = "abraaobarros3@gmail.com, luciano.hg4@gmail.com, leonardofliborio@gmail.com, bertazzolla@gmail.com"
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = "Release Notes for this build."
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.+'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.0-beta.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:1.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Alguém que saiba ou tenha resolvido me ajude por favor. Muito obrigado!

Erro testEmail:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Olá, Henrique. Por favor, coloque a mensagem de erro como texto no corpo da pergunta, para facilitar as buscas futuras e permitir a leitura por usuários de leitores de tela.

Comment: São várias, por isso a imagem. Mas vou colocar uma.

Comment: Coloque pelo menos a que está na imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe este caso abaixo:

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

// Testes para MapsActivity
public class MapsActivityInstrumentationTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MapsActivity.class);

     // Verifica se no EditText tem o texto "Hello"
    @Test
    public void validaEditText() {
        onView(withId(R.id.etInput)).perform(typeText("Hello")).check(matches(withText("Hello")));
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Para mais detalhes, dê uma lida [neste artigo](http://luizmarcus.com/android/executando-teste-instrumentado-com-o-framework-espresso/).

Você pode conferir uma lista de métodos do Espresso na [documentação do Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/Espresso.html).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não há este "startservice" no activityTestRule .. Não o acho após o ponto e colocando-o, fica em "vermelho".

Comment: Deu certo aqui. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @HenriqueMendes se precisar, dê um grito! Abs

Comment: @HenriqueMendes queria só te avisar que o que você está fazendo é um diferencial nas empresas. Seja um bom desenvolvedor e um excelente tester, vale a pena.

Comment: Obrigagdo. Tentando começar com TDD. To começando ainda. Agradeço novamente e pode ficar de olho que virão mais perguntas hah